# Adding second comments.php for reviews

Tags: custom-post-types, comments

I've just started a business directory website. I'm using a custom post type for this. I'd like to extend the site's purpose by allowing visitors to add reviews on each business.

I therefore wondered if I could create another comments.php file for the purpose of visitors leaving reviews on single business pages while leaving the original comments.php for blog comments. Of course, I've tried a few review plug-ins without success!

Comment: While I want to leave your question open, I also want to ask you to read [ask], file an [edit] to your question and rephrase it. Verbosity helps both ends and showing at least your research, efforts and fails helps avoiding routes that you already have tried. Keep in mind that "I used plugin X" is not trying to solve this as this site is about _developement_, not installing plugins. Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope that make it's easier to understand - I do apologize for any confusion or lack of detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your `comments.php` looks like, so I cannot tell how to adapt your current code, but I can generally tell you how to approach this.

Normally, WP will assume that you want the latest comments of the current post. If you want something else, you start with the condition under which you want your second set of comments to show and add this to `comments.php`: `if (my_condition) { show second comments set; }`

Now, you have to tell WP which set of comments to use. You need to set `$args` which are available in the [`get_comments`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) function. There are too many options to describe here.

Once you have retrieved comments with `$comments=get_comments($args);` you can feed them into the display function [`wp_list_comments($args,$comments)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments). The `$args` to this function determine how the comments are displayed. You can have them shown completely different from you other comments set.

Comment: Thanks for you input. I'm using the standard comments.php. Can I start by copying it and rename it [to something like comments-review.php] ?

Comment: Yes, of course you can. If you have different templates for blog and review pages, you can simply call different comment templates from there. You can also edit the `$args` for `comment_form` if you want different input fields

Comment: Great! I'll have a go and ask about customizing the $args later. Thanks again cjbj

Comment: I've had a play and got it working! So thanks for your help. My next two questions are can I remove the "reply" after each comment? and how should i go back adding rating stars?

Comment: @ajguitars The first question depends on your theme and the second on a plugin. While both _would_ be follow up questions, they are not as third party software is off topic.

Comment: Thanks Kaiser! I've managed to remove the reply link and avater. So i'll look into plugins!